# AWS account hacked! Amazon isn't helping. What can I do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hacking

Recently, someone hacked my AWS account by getting into the email account used for AWS and requesting a password change. Afterwards, they obviously changed the password of the email address. Amazon seems to be pretty clueless and insists that the only way to verify ownership is the email address, rather than any kind of personal or billing information. How can I get my account back?

Comment: So, contact the email provider and regain control of the email account...

Answer (score 2):

You should've set up two factor authentication before this happened as per best practice, at least for the root account that has access to billing information. Now you've lost ownership the only people who can help are Amazon. Call Amazon back, validate with your credit card, take control back. There aren't really any other good options, other than what Michael said above.